# creating mean (event logged) time course from longer time course in matlab

Tags: matlab, time-series

I have a vector (which is basically a timecourse).

```
t=rand(1,20)'
```

I now want to extract a mean timecourse of the bins 1 to 3, 4 to 6, 7 to 9 and so on.

I could do this in a step by step way using mean

```
first=mean(t(1:3:end);
second=mean(t(2:3:end);
third=mean(t(3:3:end);
```

and then using vertcat to create my mean vector

```
mean_ts=vertcat(first,second,third);
```

This is a lot of code for a simple task, though, and I don't get standard deviation etc. which would be nice..
Is there a command, that could do this for me more easily?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You could extend your vector with nan values to make it a multiple of 3

```
q = 3 - mod(numel(t),3);
t = [t; nan(q,1)];
```

Then reshape your vector, after which you can compute means and stds columnwise, like this:

```
k = reshape(t,3,numel(t)/3)';
mn = nanmean(k)
st = nanstd(k)
```

Comment: Has to be pretty fast! +1

Comment: @biebobob: the above is based on your code snippet, but in the description you indicate that you like to have the means for 1:3, 4:6, ... For the latter case, you should change the reshape into `k = reshape(t,numel(t)/3,3);`.

Comment: Looks easy, and yes your're right, the code snippet actually represents what I wanted. Thanks for the answer, think I'll use reshape then!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html)** for a one-liner -

```
mean_ts = arrayfun(@(n) mean(t(n:3:numel(t))),1:3)
```

Replace `mean` with `std` to have the standard deviation values.

---

Or another one-liner based on **[`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)** and **[`vec2mat`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html)** -

```
mean_ts = nanmean(reshape(vec2mat(t,3*ceil(numel(t)/3),nan),3,[]),2)
```

Replace `nanmean` with `nanstd` to have the standard deviation values.